# Public Intents for Other Applications to Use

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating an app with a service, and I would like other apps to be able to interact with and extend it. I can think of two scenarios:

1. another app wants to interact with the service
2. someone develops a better version of the service that they would
   like my app to use instead of my built-in service

Most of the things that I have read about actions say that you should name your action something like `com.mycompany.appname.CUSTOM_ACTION`. However, I do not think I should put the actions in my own namespace since other developers might want their apps to be able to receive them. Instead, I think they should give them a more public name, like `intent.action.CUSTOM_ACTION`.

Is there a convention for naming public actions? Is it ok that I name my actions like `intent.action.CUSTOM_ACTION`, or is that a no-no?

Answer (score 0):

It's bad idea to give it generic names. It comes with your app and therefore you should stick to `com.mycompany.appname.CUSTOM_ACTION` namespace

Answer (score 0):

[openintents.org](http://www.openintents.org/en/intentstable) is a website that appears to allow developers to register intents that they want other applications to use.